# Using emacs in batch mode to dump a file with syntax highlighting?

Tags: emacs, syntax-highlighting

I'd like to use emacs in some kind of batch mode to just render a file with syntax highlighting and exit. Specifically, I want to dump the fontified buffer with ANSI escape codes so that it shows up reasonably syntax-highlighted on my terminal. Is there any way to do this?

The [ansi-lpr.el](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/gnu-emacs-sources/2005-03/msg00007.html) library seems to be kind of along the lines of what I want, but the output isn't colorified. I can't figure out how to get over that final hurdle — there are a lot of modules to digest ANSI escape codes into Emacs text properties (e.g. [ansi-color.el](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ansi-color.el)) but I haven't found anything that does the reverse. If anyone can point me to something that does, I think I can piece together the rest.

Alternatively, I've seen some hacky approaches like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13420160/3760486) (using `script` and capturing the output) but in my experiments that approach has seemed unlikely to be fruitful — you get tons of undesirable control sequences mixed in with the highlighted text.

The overarching motivation here is to use emacs in a `$LESSOPEN` pipe to get syntax highlighting when I page files. In case you're going to say it, I've tried and "just page files in Emacs" is not acceptable for me.

Comment: What format do you want the colors in? ANSI color escapes seem to be what you want, but I'm not sure even that will work. Would Emacs buffer ==> HTML ==> text do?

Comment: @PythonNut: Yes, I want ANSI color codes. I haven't experimented with Emacs => HTML => text; I'd be skeptical that that could work well, but depending on the HTML output I suppose it might actually not be too bad.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm glad to announce a new package, **e2ansi**, that (hopefully) does what you asked for.

The package provides a command-line tool `e2ansi-cat` that starts Emacs in batch mode, opens files, syntax highlight them (using font-lock), and creates ANSI-colored versions of the syntax highlighted files.

You can integrate this into `less` by setting the following variables to, for example:

```
export "LESSOPEN=|emacs --batch -Q -l ~/.emacs -l bin/e2ansi-cat %s"
export "LESS=-R"
export MORE=$LESS
```

The end result looks like the following:

[image: Example]

You can vary the colors and attributes like bold, underline, and
italics by using a suitable Emacs theme.

The e2ansi package is located at https://github.com/Lindydancer/e2ansi

#### Personal note

I would like to thank you for posting this question, it directly inspired me to write e2ansi.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you! I have custom colors set up in my .emacs using `custom-set-faces` calls. These don't seem to be used by e2ansi. Is that expected? Is there a way to get them to be applied? The `--theme` option sounds most relevant but I don't know anything about Emacs theming.

Comment: Yes, your personal color settings is expected to work. However, when using the --batch option, Emacs don't read your personal init file. Hence, you must explicitly load it using a `-l` option. In the example for `less` in the answer I have assumed that it is named `~/.emacs`.

Comment: Ah, great! I've started giving it a try. [First issue filed](https://github.com/Lindydancer/e2ansi/issues/1), we'll see if any more pop up ...

Comment: Very nice. Can you add a bit on what you had to do to handle batch mode, in particular wrt font-locking, for example? Connecting this answer to e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3591337/emacs-htmlize-in-batch-mode would be very nice, too.

Comment: @Clément, in batch mode, font-lock normally won't enable itself. I guess this makes sense if you only see font-lock as a way to get syntax highlighting in Emacs frames, which you won't need in batch mode. Hence, for this kind of application you will have to trick font-lock into believing it's not in batch mode. I do this by setting `noninteractive` to nil: `(let ((noninteractive nil)) (font-lock-mode 1))`. Secondly, font-lock mode doesn't highlight the entire buffer, only the visible parts, so you will have to do something like `(font-lock-fontify-region (point-min) (point-max))`.

Comment: Thanks! I figured parts of this in the meantime, though in my application I ended up not using a noninteractive Emacs. I'll probably write about on emacs-dev at some point :)